# How to solve this problem : A glass sphere of radius 1 m and refractive index 1.5 is silvered...?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

> **Problem:** A glass sphere of radius 1 m and refractive index 1.5 is silvered at its back. A point object is kept at a distance of 1 m from the front face, as shown in the figure. Find the position of final image.
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I know but i have been searching for a solution to this question from weeks no one was able to solve it. See if you can post a solution.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).